# Can't type into Facebook's JavaScript Test Console

Tags: facebook

I can't figure out how to use http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

Am I supposed to type my requests in the big white square?
I can not type anything inside (after logging in and accepting the application. Tried on Ubuntu Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is broken.  Using the Developer Tools in Chrome there are a load of JavaScript errors.

I would suggest reporting it to Facebook possibly [via their forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/).

[image: Facebook JavaScript Test Console Errors]

Comment: Thanks! Reported: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=312467